# How do I say 'and/or' in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have something that I can't get my head around... been trying for quite a while already.

I have this snippet of jQuery:

```
$("#amp").on('change', function () { 
    $("#cab").prop('disabled', $(this).val() == "Combo Models - 22W");
    $("#cab option").prop("selected", true);
});
```

I need to duplicate this exact bit of code 4 times but I need to change 'Combo Models - 22W' to 4 different things.

I tried duplicating the code 4 times and changing the property but it didn't work.

Is there a way of saying something like:

```
$("#cab").prop('disabled', $(this).val() == "Combo Models - 22W" OR "Combo Models - 50W" OR "Combo Models - 75W");
```

...but a snippet that actually works? thanks!

Comment: `&&` - and, `||` - or

Comment: if, else, &&, ||: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_conditions.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store all the values in a hash map. Like this:

```
var map = {};
map["Combo Models - 22W"] = true;
map["Combo Models - 50W"] = true;
map["Combo Models - 75W"] = true;
```

And so on.

Then you could just use:

```
$("#cab").prop('disabled', false || map[$(this).val()]);
```

If the string obtained by using `map[$(this).val()` is in the hash map, then `map[$(this).val()` evaluates to `true`. Otherwise it evaluates to `undefined`. Then the `false || undefined` part becomes a simple, explicit `false`.

Comment: Thank you this works a treat! Any idea how I'd return back from that though?
The #cab select remains disabled even when I go back to other options where it shouldn't disabled it.
I tried 'return true' but it's not doing anything :/

Comment: No worries - I actually got around this by adding further entries into the map var but setting the other entries to 'false' - thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry for taking long to reply. I don't understand what you mean by returning true. As for setting other possible values to false, if you did that, then you don't need the left side of the `false || map[$...]` expression.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression might be useful in this situation.

```
var modelsExp = /^Combo Models - (22|50|75)W$/;

$("#amp").on('change', function () { 
    $("#cab").prop('disabled', modelsExp.test($(this).val());
    $("#cab option").prop("selected", true);
});
```

Comment: Although I would assume these values are the result of some database query and it would therefore be better just to check against a variable with those results. I really like the idea of using regex to solve this problem as well.

Comment: @keyneom That's certainly possible. One caveat there, though, if the number of values were large I'd be tempted to handle it server-side and validate with AJAX to prevent writing a large map to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.

```
$("#cab").prop('disabled', ( $(this).val() == "Combo Models - 22W" ) || ( $(this).val() == "Combo Models - 50W" ) || ( $(this).val() == "Combo Models - 75W" ));
```

Nonetheless, I would guess there is a better answer to your original problem than doing something like this. You should be able to use some kind of variable in place of hard coding those strings.